# What's the limit on the size of ODataActionParameters?

Tags: c#, asp.net, odata

I'm uploading a decent-sized chunk of JSON to an OData v4 Action handled by C# ASP.NET. At a certain point, I see that instead of properly parsing the input, the ODataActionParameters param is simply null, and the server throws a null pointer exception.

The data I'm uploading *can* be split into chunks, but it's a) unwieldy to do so and b) can cause a little bit of data loss when I do that. (I'm uploading events to a simulator; the input is often segmentable, since there are groupings in it, but isn't guaranteed to be segmentable - there might just be one grouping.)

So at what point does ODataActionParameters crumple under the load of bytes? I'm doing some terribly un-scientific "throw it at the wall and see what sticks" testing at the moment, but if someone can tell me what the limit is, that would make my life much easier. (Also, is there a way to extend that limit for just a couple of endpoints? Is it configurable?)

Comment: `ODataActionParameters` is just an alias for `Dictionary<string, object>`, and it is not tunable. Can you provide a stack trace to show where the exception happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the limitation was in the system.web httpRuntime configuration, not in the ODataActionParameters itself. The solution was to change web.config to allow a larger maxRequestLength:

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6" maxRequestLength="204800" />
    ....and other settings...
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

The default maxRequestLength is 4MB. I set it to 200MB here because various OData bits around my app set up a maxReceivedMessageSize of 200MB. (The true limit for a particular request is the *lower* of your OData config for that request and the httpRuntime config.)